# Fullscreen mode is disabled for an embedded YouTube video in WKWebView

Tags: ios, youtube, wkwebview

I am trying to embed a YouTube video in a web page loaded in a `WKWebView`.

Here's the page source:

```
let html = """
<html><head>
<title>YouTube Video</title>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no, user-scalable=no">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

</head>
<body>
  Here is an embedded youtube video: <br/> 
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/oR-6N1Dc_zc?modestbranding=1&rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> 
  <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/270611565" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</body>
</html>
"""
```

Configuration of the WKWebView is close to default (`allowsInlineMediaPlayback` is enabled). The web page is loaded with `webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)`.

The fullscreen mode button in YouTube player is greyed out. When I click it, the following message is displayed: "Your browser does not support full screen.":

[image: video player message]

I get the same message if I use `UIWebView` instead. Fullscreen mode seems to work for an embedded Vimeo video (although the Vimeo player just seems to ignore the `allowfullscreen` attribute of the `iframe`) and a video embedded using the `<video>` tag. When I load a video from the YouTube website, fullscreen mode works (although it looks more like some kind of emulation, not like the native fullscreen mode).

The question is: **why is the fullscreen mode disabled and is there a way to enable it?**

Comment: I’m 99% sure this is a Google policy decision rather than anything you’re doing. Strangely, it (currently) works on iPhone, but on iPad they seem to want to push you to the app.

Comment: @Chris I have the same suspicion, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Plenty of others have reached the same conclusion, e.g. https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/can’t-go-full-screen-while-watching-youtube-in-safari.2117748/ and https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/youtube-in-ios-safari.2113012/

Comment: It *might* be solvable with a bookmarklet, but expecting your users to configure that is probably unreasonable.

Comment: @AndriiChernenko did  you try iamszabo answer ? It worked for me.

Comment: @CedricSoubrie I didn't, and I won't be able to, but if you say it works, I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can solve the issue by disabling inline media.

```
let webViewConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
webViewConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = false
WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webViewConfiguration)
```

Comment: This sadly disables inline playback (obvsly) so you're forced to choose always fullscreen or never fullscreen which isn't ideal. But better than not having fullscreen at all